# function of two parameters and its derivatives

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Suppose $f(z,\alpha)>0$. Also suppose

$\frac{d f(z,\alpha)}{d \alpha}=-g(z)-h(z) f(z,\alpha)$

for some increasing functions $g(z)$ and positive increasing function $h(z)$.

If we show that $f(z,\alpha=1)$ is non-decreasing in $z$, can we say $f(z,\alpha)$ is non-decreasing in $z$ for $0<\alpha<1$.

Note we essentially have $\frac{d^2 f(z,\alpha)}{d \alpha\, d z}<0$ at $\alpha=1$.